# Update flutter card data one by one

Tags: android, flutter

I'm experimenting with flutter, creating a small screen to fetch cryptocurrency data. I have three crypto name (BTC, ETH, LTC), each will be displayed on card, the rate on USD.
I can get the data for each currency, and display it. But in my code, if each data fetch took 1 second, the cards display will be updated after 3 seconds. All data will be fetched first, then screen updated using `setState()`.

This is the initial working code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'coin_data.dart' as coinData;

class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PriceScreenState createState() => _PriceScreenState();
}

class _PriceScreenState extends State<PriceScreen> {
  String _selectedCurrency = "USD";

  List<coinData.CoinData> _coinData = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Coin Ticker'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          buildCoinCards(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Card buildCoinCard(coinData.CoinData currentCoinData) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 28.0),
        child: Text(
          '1 ${currentCoinData.coinName()} =  ${currentCoinData.last} $_selectedCurrency',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildCoinCards() {
    List<Card> coinCards = [];

    for (var currentCoinData in _coinData) {
      coinCards.add(
        buildCoinCard(currentCoinData),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: coinCards,
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (String crypto in coinData.cryptoList) {
      _coinData.add(
        coinData.CoinData(
          last: 0,
          displaySymbol: "$crypto-$_selectedCurrency",
        ),
      );
    }

    updateCoinData();
  }

  void updateCoinData() async {
    var coinDataFetch =
        await coinData.CoinData().getAllCoinData(_selectedCurrency);

    setState(() {
      _coinData = coinDataFetch;
    });
  }
}
```

I'd like to update each item everytime a HTTP call is success. So the card will be updated one by one (took 1 second each) instead of waiting for 3 seconds. So I change the `updateCoinData()` to this, but it's not working.

```dart
  void updateCoinData() async {
    for (coinData.CoinData currentCoinData in _coinData) {
      var fetchCoinData = await currentCoinData.getCoinData(
          currentCoinData.coinName(), _selectedCurrency);

      setState(() {
        currentCoinData = fetchCoinData;
        print(
            currentCoinData.coinName() + " " + currentCoinData.last.toString());
      });
    }
  }
```

I suppose I cannot update the `List` item on `setState()`?
How do I achieve this update one-by-one?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are doing exercise from the flutter course by London App Brewery. Why don't you  check their completed code for answer .

Comment: Already did. In the final complete code, it did the same thing as my `updateData`, thus will wait until all data fetched before updating the cards

Comment: I can think of 2 ways for now. not sure if it is feasible. just a raw idea. 1. Call -get Response - update UI for 3 API separately. You'll have to create 3 different variables & update them 2. maybe streams can help here. where you'll update the stream once you receive the response of each API & update UI accordingly.